How to modify a Laravel request when POST data is sent as `null`?
There are times when my front-end clients are sending null as the entirety of a request payload for a POST call:

Unfortunately, this is now causing an issue in my middleware:

JSON content was expected to decode to an array, "null" returned.

This is the line of code in my middleware file:
$response = $next($request);

Which throws the error from Symfony: Request.php:
if (!\is_array($content)) {
    throw new JsonException(sprintf('JSON content was expected to decode to an array, "%s" returned.', get_debug_type($content)));
}

This only appears to occur in my live server environments (Forge) and not locally (Valet-served).
I am able to catch this before the $next() function is called, but I'm not sure how to modify the request object to allow it to pass through:
if ($request->getContent() === 'null' || $request->getContent() === null) {
    $request->replace([]); // still hits the null-error
}

There must be some way of catching this and modifying it before it goes through, but I can't quite figure it out. Any ideas?

Why not check why the frontend sends an invalid request, and fix the problem exactly where it occurs?

Interesting issue; I of course would recommend your front-end clients stop sending null, but something something users something something. Could you maybe try catching that JsonException and allowing code to continue execution?

"There must be some way of catching this and modifying it before it goes through" Why do you want to do that? If the client is not supposed to send null, then throwing an exception is fine.

This was not an issue until either a PHP upgrade or a recent Laravel (8 to 10) upgrade. So I would rather fix the issue without affecting all clients that are sending this. Noting that this would be a lot of Roku TV app deployments.

You could default to empty array:
$response = $next($request ?? []);

And you cannot exclude the possibility that you may get a request like the one you haves shown.
If this suggestion will not fulfill the goal, then you might consider $request->getContent() ?? [] or something.
Otherwise, if it still fails, then you will need to look into how your object looks alike and what exactly failed to be parsed. In that case you will need to edit your question and provide further debugging details.

$request is a huge object in Laravel, I doubt ?? [] would coalesce it to an empty array there, but I can't say I've tried this, so maybe? (That edit is much better )

Beware that the content is 'null' (a string), not null.

Unfortunately I can't just pass an empty array into $next() as the variable passed in is expected to be a Request object.
